# Did Aristotle make a mistake in the Prior Analytics, Part 5?

Tags: logic, aristotle

Did Aristotle make a mistake in Part 5 of the prior analytics?

“If the middle term is related universally to one of the extremes, a particular negative syllogism must result whenever the middle term is related universally to the major whether positively or negatively, and particularly to the minor and in a manner opposite to that of the universal statement: by 'an opposite manner' I mean, if the universal statement is negative, the particular is affirmative: if the universal is affirmative, the particular is negative. For if M belongs to no N, but to some O, it is necessary that N does not belong to some O. For since the negative statement is convertible, N will belong to no M: but M was admitted to belong to some O: therefore N will not belong to some O: for the result is reached by means of the first figure. Again if M belongs to all N, but not to some O, it is necessary that N does not belong to some O: for if N belongs to all O, and M is predicated also of all N, M must belong to all O: but we assumed that M does not belong to some O. And if M belongs to all N but not to all O, we shall conclude that N does not belong to all O: the proof is the same as the above. But if M is predicated of all O, but not of all N, there will be no syllogism. Take the terms animal, substance, raven; animal, white, raven. Nor will there be a conclusion when M is predicated of no O, but of some N. Terms to illustrate a positive relation between the extremes are animal, substance, unit: a negative relation, animal, substance, science.”

He says there’s a conclusion for “all N is M, some O is not M,” namely some O is not N. But then he says there’s no conclusion for “all O is M, some N is not M,” which I’d assume to be some N is not O

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108995/discussion-on-question-by-gunog-selrack-did-aristotle-make-a-mistake-in-the-prio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Revised edition*

The 2nd figure is defined as follows: the Middle is predicated in both premises and 1st premise is universal.

The valid syllogism in this figure are: **EAE, AEE, EIO** and **AOO**.

Example of **AOO** (*Baroco*):

> if M belongs to all N, but not to some O, it is necessary that N does not belong to some O.

We use [Alexander of Aphrodisias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_of_Aphrodisias)' commentary [see [On Aristotle Prior Analytics 1.14-22](https://books.google.it/books/about/On_Aristotle_Prior_Analytics_1_14_22.html?id=gPbjAAAAMAAJ), page 155].

We can compare Alexander's comment to Aristotle counterexample method in *An.Prior*, 26a9-12:

> Nor can a deduction be formed when neither the first term belongs to any of the middle, nor the middle to any of the last [i.e. "A si predicated of no B" and "B is predicated of no C" is invalid.]

In this case, the two instances provided show that the truth of the premises is compatible both with an **A** and an **E** conclusion. But they entails respectively **I** and **O** [see [The Square of Opposition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square)], and thus the **EE** form is not valid.

What about the two passages discussed above ?

The first is a counterexample to an **OA** form:

> if M is predicated of all O, but not of all N, there will be no syllogism. Take the terms animal, substance, raven; animal, white, raven.

*I think that the key-point is: we cannot exchange the two premises*.

> > If so, the conclusion must express a relation of predication between the *major* (O) and the *minor* (N): "raven is predicated (not predicated) of all (some) substance (animal)"

The counterexamples use for **M,N,O**: animal, substance, raven; animal, white, raven.

With the first three terms we have that the 1st premise is: "animal (M) is predicated of every raven (O)", and the 2nd one is: "animal (M) is not predicated of every substance (N)".

But "substance (N) is predicated of every raven (O)" which means that "raven is predicated of some substance".

The conclusion is **I**, which implies that the premises cannot validly conclude with **E** (the contradictory of **I**).

But, at the same time, "raven is not predicated of some substance" is false, and thus the premises cannot validly conclude with **O**.

With the next three terms we have that the 1st premise is: "animal (M) is predicated of every raven (O)", and the 2nd one is: "animal (M) is not predicated of every white (N)".

But "white (N) is predicated of no raven (O)", i.e. "raven is predicated of no white", which is an **E** proposition.

This implies that the premises cannot validly conclude with **I** (the contradictory of **I**). But **E** implies **O**, and thus also **A** is excluded.

---

*Conclusion*:

> > if we agree that we cannot exchange major and minor premises, and thus **OA** is different from **AO**, there is no **OA** valid syllogism in the 2nd figure.

Comment: animal, substance, raven; animal, white, raven. But if we treat this as AOO, it will be valid right? All ravens are animals. Some substances are not animals. Some substances are not ravens.